# how to change color on hover in CSS grid

Tags: css, hover, css-grid

I'm trying to add a hover effect to this CSS grid with no success. I tried transition and opacity techniques but to no avail. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!
Below is the code or here's the page I'm working on:  https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageID=3389

```css
@media screen and (min-width:850px) {    
    .cards {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        column-gap: 10px;
    }
}


.card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(102, 153, 102, .9);
    padding: 2rem;
    height: 6rem;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 2s;
}

.cards a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.cards .card:hover {
    background-color: rgb(102, 153, 102);
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align: center;">List of Neuro-Ophthalmic Conditions</h2>

<section class="cards">
<div class="card"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/anisocoria"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;">Anisocoria</span></strong></a></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/GiantCellArteritis" target="_blank">Giant Cell Arteritis</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=4166" target="_blank">Homonymous Hemianopsia</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/IIH">Idiopathic Intracranial Hypertension/ Pseudotumor Cerebri</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=4188" target="_blank">Leber Hereditary Optic Neuropathy</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=4155" target="_blank">Myasthenia Gravis</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/drusen">Optic Disc Drusen</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/PituitaryTumor">Pituitary Tumor</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/ThyroidEyeDisease" target="_blank">Thyroid Eye Disease</a></span></strong></div>

<div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/TransientVisualLoss" target="_blank">Transient Visual Loss</a></span></strong></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must target the `:hover` selector on the element with the `.card` class, like this:

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(102, 153, 102, 0.9);
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 6rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 2s;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #336699;
}

.cards a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="card"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/anisocoria"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;">Anisocoria</span></strong></a></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/GiantCellArteritis" target="_blank">Giant Cell Arteritis</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=4166" target="_blank">Homonymous Hemianopsia</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/IIH">Idiopathic Intracranial Hypertension/ Pseudotumor Cerebri</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=4188" target="_blank">Leber Hereditary Optic Neuropathy</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=4155" target="_blank">Myasthenia Gravis</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/drusen">Optic Disc Drusen</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/PituitaryTumor">Pituitary Tumor</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/ThyroidEyeDisease" target="_blank">Thyroid Eye Disease</a></span></strong></div>

  <div class="card"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="https://www.nanosweb.org/TransientVisualLoss" target="_blank">Transient Visual Loss</a></span></strong></div>
</section>
```